# wifi driver problem in Acer Aspire f15

Tags: drivers, wireless

yes,i already tried every thing in askubuntu and ubuntu forums and have no idea .Please help me or at least suggest me a linux distro which supports wifi driver in Acer Aspire F15

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: as pilot6 said please provide output of the command  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` so we can understand what is the problem exactly!!!

Comment: It is working properly with elementary os loki.